# Where does kubernetes store the cluster data other than etcd?

Tags: kubernetes, backup, etcd

I am trying to take a backup of the Kubernetes cluster without using any third-party applications.

I tried backing up `/var/lib/etcd`, But etcd is only changed when there is a change in namespaces. There is no change in etcd when there is a change in pods or replica sets. Is there any other location where Kubernetes stores its data other than `/var/lib/etcd`?

Comment: Could you tell me, which version of k8s which is your cloud provider and which system did you use?

Comment: We are using k8s version 1.18.1. This is mainly for an on-prem deployment where we don't have a cloud service provider such as AWS

Comment: @AkhilKolla, could you explain me, what exactly do you want to backup? For example you can make a snapshot of volumes. "Volume snapshots provide Kubernetes users with a standardized way to copy a volume's contents at a particular point in time without creating an entirely new volume. This functionality enables, for example, database administrators to backup databases before performing edit or delete modifications." More info here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volume-snapshots/

Comment: You can also make a sidecar container for logging. These logs can tell you what has changed and how: https://logz.io/blog/a-practical-guide-to-kubernetes-logging/

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak I am trying to take a backup of the Kubernetes cluster details, not the volumes. The solution I am looking for should be able to restore the cluster to a prior state.

Comment: @AkhilKolla, thanks for explanation. `etcdctl backup` command should help you. Of course, you can restore this backup in the future. Here is  the complete tutorial: https://etcd.io/docs/v2.3/admin_guide/#disaster-recovery.

Alternatively you can make a built-in snapshot using command: `etcdctl snapshot save` - more info here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-upgrade-etcd/#built-in-snapshot 
Then you can restore it - more info here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-upgrade-etcd/#restoring-an-etcd-cluster

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak. Thanks for the response. I understand etcdctl does a full backup. Can you please recommend a way to do incriminate backup so as to not backup the whole cluster every time?

Comment: @AkhilKolla, "Incremental backup of etcd, where full snapshot is taken first and then we apply watch and persist the logs accumulated over certain period to snapshot store. Restore process, restores from the full snapshot, start the embedded etcd and apply the logged events one by one." - https://github.com/gardener/etcd-backup-restore/pull/29/files. Here is full topic: https://github.com/gardener/etcd-backup-restore/issues/2. So first backup is always full. You can also see this tutorial to set up automatic, incremental backups: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yb7OUBv8cao

Comment: @AkhilKolla, Please also let me know if the cluster backup problem was resolved. I need to post a summary answer for the community.

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak thank you , the problem is resolved

Answer (score 0):

You can backup your Kubernetes cluster by command: `etcdctl backup`. Here is completely guide, how to use [etcdctl backup command](https://etcd.io/docs/v2.3/admin_guide/#disaster-recovery).

Alternatively you can also make a [snapshot](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-upgrade-etcd/#built-in-snapshot) of your cluster:  `etcdctl snapshot save`.
This command will let you create **incremental backup**.

> Incremental backup of etcd, where full snapshot is taken first and then we apply watch and persist the logs accumulated over certain period to snapshot store. Restore process, restores from the full snapshot, start the embedded etcd and apply the logged events one by one.

You can find more about incremental backup function [here](https://github.com/gardener/etcd-backup-restore/issues/2).